# How do programs take advantage of Ghostscript if it is not in Environment Path?

Tags: path, ghostscript

I installed Ghostscript from this link:

http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/gs904w32.exe

so that I could view .**eps** files with **Irfanview** and so that **Imagemagick** is able to convert JPG files to EPS files and vice versa.

After a next/next/next install, I can indeed now view the .eps files and convert to and from jpg <--> eps.

However, I would assume Ghostscript had written into the **enivronment path** as Imagemagick did, so that these other programs could use it, I even remember seeing in the text in the .eps file that it was trying to access "gswin32".

But Ghostscript is not in the enivronment path, and when I go to the command line and type "**gswin32**" it tells me file not found.

**How do these other programs use Ghostscript if not through the environment path or being told where it where the executable is located (C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.04\bin\gswin32.exe).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a registry entry with its path? That would seem to be the natural windowsishy solution.